# Use the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem to prove the following

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Use the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem which is Every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence to prove the following:

A continuous function deﬁned on a closed, bounded interval must be bounded. That is, let $f$ be a continuous function deﬁned on $[a,b]$. Then there exists a positive real number $B$ such that $|f(x)|≤ B$ for all $x ∈ [a,b]$.

could you please help me how can I prove it?

Comment: This is such a poor question that was simply copy-pasted (look at the `ﬁ` in the question instead of `fi`), with no context and no effort shown. Did you read the [How-to-ask](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice?) page that is shown when you signed up, including the linked [How to ask a good question page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The prototypical proof is a proof by contradiction.  We assume that $f$ is continuous and unbounded on $[a,b]$.

Then, for any $n$ there exists a number $x_n\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_n)>n$.

Since $x_n$ is bounded, there exists a subsequence, say $x_{n_k}$ that converges to a number $x_0\in [a,b]$.

Inasmuch as $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, it is continuous at $x_0$ and hence $f(x_{n_k})\to f(x_0)$.

This means that $f(x_{n_k})$ is bounded which contradicts the statement that $f(x_{n_k})>n_k$.

Therefore, $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$.

Comment: however even unbounded sequences can have a converging subsequence, so that makes this proof wrong

Comment: @josephrock What on earth are you babbling about? The sequence $x_{n_k}\in [a,b]$ and is BOUNDED!  So the proof is valid!

Comment: i am saying a sequence that is unbounded can have a converging subsequence too , so this prove would work for the unbounded sequence too, however it is clear that an unbounded sequence cannot be bounded too

Comment: there could be f(x) that are unbounded as the sequence x(nk) does not take into account all the x values

Comment: @josephrock You said "so that makes this proof wrong."  The proof is valid.  The fact that an unbounded sequence can have a convergent subsequence is irrelevant.  Not ALL unbounded sequences have a convergent subsequence.  So, again, what are you talking about?

Comment: what i am saying is your proof misses out on points that could be unbounded, as the converging sequence is not a representation of all the points in the sequence, there might be an xk such that f(xk) is unbounded..

Comment: The proof assumes that $f$ IS unbounded and finds a contradiction!  What do you fail to see here?

Comment: As the BW theorem only finds a subsequence that converges, there could be other points in the sequence that diverges is what I am saying

Comment: @josephrock The subsequence $\{n_k\}$ converges to $x_0$.  But this means that $f(x_{n_k})$ is not greater than $n_k$, which WAS ASSUMED!.  That gives the desired contradiction.

Comment: ()  is the function of the sequence, while n is the number of the sequence, example: f(x5) vs 5, I don't think they can be compared

Comment: @josephrock I suggest you either read the proof again and try to understand it or learn a bit more math including the definitions of infinite sequences and subsequence.  Here is a [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence)

Comment: sorry i think you are right but i am so confused by wikipedia too, can i ask for a favor that could you explain why if we take a subsequence using the BW theorem , it accounts for all the sequences, i mean aren't we missing out something here

Comment: i mean it is possible for function to be unbounded at some part of the function and bounded at the other part, so i am thinking it is bounded at the converging sequence, but for the rest of the sequence it could be unbounded..

Answer (score 5):

Let $M=\sup f([a,b])$ ($M$ can eventually be $\infty$), we will show that this $M$ is reached for a certain $x\in[a,b]$ thus $M$ will be finite.

By definitions of $M$, $\exists (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x_n)\rightarrow M$.

$x_n$ is bounded so we can apply Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, let $x_{\phi(n)}\rightarrow d\in [a,b]$, where $(x_{\phi(n)})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a subsequence.

$f$ is continuous in $d$ so $f(x_{\phi(n)})\rightarrow f(d)$. By unicity of the limit $M=f(d)$ thus $M$ is finite. Can do the same with $m=\inf f([a,b])$. And finally take $B=\max(|m|,|M|)$ and $B<\infty$ as required.

Comment: the complete of this proof will be look like that ,Let m=inf f([a,b]) , we will show that this m is reached for a certain x∈[a,b]  thus m is finite. By definitions of m, ∃(xn)∈[a,b] such that f(xn)→m.
So , there exists a positive real number B=max(|m|,|M|) such that |f(x)|≤ B for all x ∈ [a,b].
is it correct?

Comment: You still need to extract a convergent subsequence from $(x_n)$ with Bolzano Weierstrass.

Comment: like what you did above ?

Comment: yes it is exactly the same reasonning